# SQL Server, 2 tables, one is input, second is database with items, find closest match

Tags: sql-server

This is my first Stackflow question, I hope someone can help me out with this. I I am completely lost and a newbie at SQL.

I have two tables (which I overly simplified for this question), the first one has the customer info and the car tire that they need. The second one is simply filled with a tire id, and all of the information for the tires. I am trying to input only the customer ID and return the one closest tire that matches the input along with the values of both the selected tire and the customer's tire. The matches also need to be prioritized in that order (size most important, width next most important, ratio is least important). Any suggestions on how to do this or where to start? Is there anything I can look at to help me solve this problem? I have been trying many different procedures, and some nested selects, but nothing is getting me close. Thank you.

**customertable** (custno, custsize, custwidth, custratio)

```
1,17,255,50
2,16,235,50
etc...
```

**tirecollection** (tireid, tiresize, tirewidth, tireratio)

```
1,15,225,40
2,16,225,50
3,17,250,55
4,17,235,30
5,18,255,40
etc...
```

Comment: If you've tried a few things, post them here so that we can help you make modifications to your query to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running SQL Server 2008 or later, this should work (this assumes you want to get a result for a single customer on a case-by-case basis):

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf.GetClosestTireMatch 
(
    @CustomerNo int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT custno, tireid, tiresize, tirewidth, tireratio
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sizediff, widthdiff, ratiodiff) AS rownum 
        , c.custno, c.custsize, c.custwidth, c.custratio, t.tireid, t.tiresize, t.tirewidth, t.tireratio
        , ABS(c.custsize-t.tiresize) AS sizediff, ABS(c.custwidth-t.tirewidth) AS widthdiff, ABS(c.custratio-t.tireratio) AS ratiodiff
        FROM (SELECT * FROM customertable WHERE custno = @CustomerNo) c
        CROSS JOIN tirecollection
    ) sub
    WHERE rownum = 1


GO
```

Then you run the function with:

```
SELECT * FROM udf.GetClosestTireMatch(5)
```

(where 5=the customernumber you're querying).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am with you for most of this. I have never used cross join before, and I am getting an error after that in the last where clause. I am also unsure of what the last "c"  is right before the cross join. When I delete that the "cross" becomes the error. I am running sql server management studio 17 developer edition.

Comment: Sorry, I made a small error. It should be fixed now. :) The "c" (and now the "sub") are just names for the subqueries: TSQL requires that subqueries be named, even if you never actually use the names.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a 100% complete solution, but may work towards coming up with a solution. The approach here is combining the tyre dimensions into one value and then ranking them within a tyre size partition. You could then pass in the customer tyre dimensions to get the closest match.

```
with CTE
as
(
    select  *, TyreSize + TyreWidth as [TyreDimensions]
    from    tblTyres
)
select  TC.CustId, C.TyreId, C.TyreSize, C.TyreWidth, C.[TyreDimensions],
    rank() over(partition by C.TyreSize order by C.[TyreDimensions]) as [RNK]
from    tblTyreCustomer as TC
join    CTE as C
on TC.CustTyreSize = C.TyreSize
```